# Update two tables simultaneous when using POST method Django

Tags: django, postgresql

So, I need your help again.

I'm struggling with a little problem and I didn't find any solution for it.

I'm having two tables in my models.py and what I want to do is to update both tables status from my models using post method.

Can you help me with any ideas? Thank you in advance.

My models.py:

```
class Chat(models.Model):
    chat_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True, blank=True)
    payload = models.CharField(max_length=299, validators=[validate])
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
    utc_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class ScheduleTable(models.Model):
  
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10)
 
views.py:

@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def get_chat(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        chat_objects = Chat.objects.all()
        chat_serialize = ChatSerializer(chat_objects, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(chat_serialize.data, safe=False)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        chat_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        chat_data['status'] = 'new'
        chat_data['chat_id'] += 1
        chat_serializer = ChatSerializer(data=chat_data)
        if chat_serializer.is_valid():
            chat_serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(chat_serializer.data,
                                status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return JsonResponse(chat_serializer.errors,
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can do something like `ScheduleTable.objects.create(status=chat_data['status'])` in addition to the `chat_serializer.save()`, I would advise you to seriously consider your database design. You're essentially adding the same column in two different tables.